# make nodes different sizes in the same image

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to make all the nodes the same size. But the problem is that some of them have more text in them so they automatically get bigger. Any help would be nice thanks.

### Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.5,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt, fill=blue!20}]  
  \node (n1) at (-5,1) {$v_{1}$}; 
  \node (n2) at (-5,6) {$v_{i}$};
  \node (n3) at (-5,11) {$v_{n}$};
  \node (n4) at (1,-5) {$u_{1}$}; 
  \node (n5) at (6,-5) {$u_{j}$};
  \node (n6) at (11,-5) {$u_{n}$};
  \node (n7) at (1,1) {$(u_{1},v_{1})$}; 
  \node (n8) at (1,6) {$(u_{1},v_{i})$};
  \node (n9) at (1,11) {$(u_{1},v_{n})$};

  \node (n10) at (6,1) {$(u_{j},v_{1})$}; 
  \node (n11) at (6,6) {$(u_{j},v_{i})$};
  \node (n12) at (6,11) {$(u_{j},v_{n})$};

  \node (n13) at (11,1) {$(u_{m},v_{1})$}; 
  \node (n14) at (11,6) {$(u_{m},v_{i})$};
  \node (n15) at (11,11) {$(u_{m},v_{n})$};

\foreach \from/\to in {n2/n3,n1/n2,n4/n5,n5/n6,n7/n8,n8/n9,n10/n11,n11/n12,n13/n14,n14/n15,n9/n12,n12/n15,n8/n11,n11/n14,n7/n10,n10/n13}
\draw[loosely dotted] (\from) -- (\to);
   \path [every node/.style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=+.1667em}] 
        (n1) edge [bend left]  node[swap] {} (n3)
        (n4) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {} (n6)
        (n9) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$a$} (n7)
        (n7) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$b$} (n13)              (n13) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$c$} (n15)
        (n15) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$d$} (n9);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a `minimum size` value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.5,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt, fill=blue!20,minimum size=39pt}]  
  \node (n1) at (-5,1) {$v_{1}$}; 
  \node (n2) at (-5,6) {$v_{i}$};
  \node (n3) at (-5,11) {$v_{n}$};
  \node (n4) at (1,-5) {$u_{1}$}; 
  \node (n5) at (6,-5) {$u_{j}$};
  \node (n6) at (11,-5) {$u_{n}$};
  \node (n7) at (1,1) {$(u_{1},v_{1})$}; 
  \node (n8) at (1,6) {$(u_{1},v_{i})$};
  \node (n9) at (1,11) {$(u_{1},v_{n})$};

  \node (n10) at (6,1) {$(u_{j},v_{1})$}; 
  \node (n11) at (6,6) {$(u_{j},v_{i})$};
  \node (n12) at (6,11) {$(u_{j},v_{n})$};

  \node (n13) at (11,1) {$(u_{m},v_{1})$}; 
  \node (n14) at (11,6) {$(u_{m},v_{i})$};
  \node (n15) at (11,11) {$(u_{m},v_{n})$};

\foreach \from/\to in {n2/n3,n1/n2,n4/n5,n5/n6,n7/n8,n8/n9,n10/n11,n11/n12,n13/n14,n14/n15,n9/n12,n12/n15,n8/n11,n11/n14,n7/n10,n10/n13}
\draw[loosely dotted] (\from) -- (\to);
   \path [every node/.style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=+.1667em}] 
        (n1) edge [bend left]  node[swap] {} (n3)
        (n4) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {} (n6)
        (n9) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$a$} (n7)
        (n7) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$b$} (n13)              (n13) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$c$} (n15)
        (n15) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$d$} (n9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you could be interested in the `positioning` library to help you place your nodes without explicit coordinates.

The code with the `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.5,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt, fill=blue!20,minimum size=38pt},node distance=1.35cm and 1.35cm]  

  \node (n7) at (1,1) {$(u_{1},v_{1})$}; 
  \node[above=of n7] (n8) {$(u_{1},v_{i})$};
  \node[above=of n8] (n9) {$(u_{1},v_{n})$};

  \node[right=of n7] (n10) {$(u_{j},v_{1})$}; 
  \node[above=of n10] (n11) {$(u_{j},v_{i})$};
  \node[above=of n11] (n12) {$(u_{j},v_{n})$};

  \node[right=of n10] (n13) {$(u_{m},v_{1})$}; 
  \node[above=of n13] (n14) {$(u_{m},v_{i})$};
  \node[above=of n14] (n15) {$(u_{m},v_{n})$};

  \node[left=of n7] (n1) {$v_{1}$}; 
  \node[above=of n1] (n2)  {$v_{i}$};
  \node[above=of n2] (n3) {$v_{n}$};

  \node[below=of n7] (n4) {$u_{1}$}; 
  \node[right=of n4] (n5)  {$u_{j}$};
  \node[right=of n5] (n6) {$u_{n}$};

\foreach \from/\to in {n2/n3,n1/n2,n4/n5,n5/n6,n7/n8,n8/n9,n10/n11,n11/n12,n13/n14,n14/n15,n9/n12,n12/n15,n8/n11,n11/n14,n7/n10,n10/n13}
\draw[loosely dotted] (\from) -- (\to);
   \path [every node/.style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=+.1667em}] 
        (n1) edge [bend left]  node[swap] {} (n3)
        (n4) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {} (n6)
        (n9) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$a$} (n7)
        (n7) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$b$} (n13)              (n13) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$c$} (n15)
        (n15) edge [bend right]  node[swap] {$d$} (n9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user90401 You're welcome. I updated my answer with an example using `positioning`.